# I get an error when I add migration using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I built a console project and use code first to map model to database. When I run the command of `Add-Migration InitialMigration`, I get an error:

> Method 'Create' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=3.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.

The `DbContext` is:

```
class ActorDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Actor> Actors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
            @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=ActorDb;"
            + "Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }
}
```

The entity is:

```
public class Actor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool AcademyWinner { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: try adding the name and specifying the context `Add-Migration -name InitialAppDbMigration -context ActorDbContext`

Answer (score 26):

I just ran into this same issue using `VS for Mac`.
My problem was I had the following versions of packages installed:

> - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools `5.0.0-preview.8.20407.4`
> - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design `5.0.0-preview.8.20407.4`
> - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer `3.1.8`

Take note of the different versions used.
To correct the issue I uninstalled the `preview` versions of the packages and installed the latest stable versions.

> - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools `3.1.8`
> - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design `3.1.8`
> - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer `3.1.8`

Again take note of the versions for all 3 packages.
Once I had installed the correct version of each package the issue was resolved and my `Add-Migration` worked.

Comment: Saved my day! Catching this issue second time. Don't understand why VS suggest to install packages of 5.x version for project with .net core 3.1

Answer (score 19):

You must include all the following packages to be of same version:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

I tried it and it run well.

Answer (score 6):

I am adding to the answer of [mohammed-abdelwahab][1]
Below packages need to be of latest update:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

For that right-click on the project --> Manage Nuget Packages --> Click on updates and just update all one by one or add if not exists as below

```
 PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
 PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
 PM> Add-Migration InitialMigration
```

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're trying to mix different versions. Make sure that all versions are aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your SqlServer to the latest version(5.0.0), I was running to exactly this same error, once I updated to the latest version it worked well.

Comment: It did worked, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when doing an old tutorial. The problem was I installed a package with the "-pre" clause.

Use the below commands:

1. Enlist installed packages in your project-

```
    PM> Get-Package -ProjectName <YourProjectName>
```

Output:

```
Id                                  Versions                                 ProjectName                     
--                                  --------                                 -----------                     
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools {5.0.0-rc.2.20475.6}                     FirstEFCoreProject              
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sq... {3.1.9}                                  FirstEFCoreProject
```

2. Uninstall the unstable package -

```
    PM> Uninstall-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

3. Reinstall the package (without the -pre) -

```
    PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

4. And then add your migration again -

```
    PM> Add-Migration InitialMigration
```

Answer (score 0):

I also just had this issue. It turns out that I accidentally had both `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` installed.

I really just needed Sqlite, so I deleted the reference to SqlServer. I then had to fix a couple of places that referenced SqlServer, instead of Sqlite, I'd missed and now the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed after running in NuGet these 2 lines

Add-Migration Initial

and then

Update-Database

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core 6.0.8
Version of **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore** should be Same for all Packages

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.8">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Error comes with this

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.0-preview.7.22376.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.8">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have both EFCore and EFFramework installed, and you want to use the Framework migration commands, then you should explicitly specify that you want to use the EFFramework migration commands, rather than the EFCore versions of those commands

```
EntityFramework6\Update-Database
```

or

```
EntityFramework6\Add-Migration
```