# TypeLoadException: Method 'Create' in type ... does not have an implementation (Error Below)

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework-core

I published my program onto an Azure Website and this error arose:

[image]

The error only seems to occur when I try to add data to the connected Azure SQL Server, or pull (some of the) data from the Azure SQL Server. Could this be a dependency issue? If so, I'm using a netcoreapp3.1 with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer version 3.1.4. Here is a further screenshot of the other NuGet packages and their versions:

[image]

I've tried to look elsewhere to find a solution to this problem, but this seems to be a one-of-a-kind issue specific to my program. Let me know if any other information is needed as I'm not sure what this error is truly rooting from.

Comment: Your package versions are incompatible. EF Core Identity 5.0.1 vs all other EF core packages. That won't work

Comment: Please add your error message and file contents as **text** or **code** to your question, not as images. See here for an explanation: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/87698)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, *the error message means that* `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory` type has a mention of `Create` method in your code/library, but it is unable to find it as there is a wrong version's reference of the **nuget package** in which `Create` method is **not** present.

*Please note that all the following packages should be of same version:*

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

For example, all of these can be of **3.1.4 version**. Check out exact same issue around this: [I get an error when I add migration using Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763225/i-get-an-error-when-i-add-migration-using-entity-framework-core)

If this does not work, you might want to check out [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/2166607.aspx?An%20unhandled%20exception%20occurred%20while%20processing%20the%20request%20) solution.

Comment: Even after unifying on exact-matching version numbers, I was still getting this error with version 3.  The only thing I was able to find that fixed it was to move to a newer major version 7.  This has the downside of losing netstandard2 compatibility with .NET Framework 4, but EF 3 is EOL now anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue after using in NuGet

Add-Migration Initial
Update-Database

Comment: Add-Migration Initial
Update-Database